# How to Use DirectPlay

Tags: directx

I am trying to follow along the book Programming a Multiplayer FPS. It is at the part to include DirectPlay, but I cannot find the header or library file for dplay8 in my DirectX installation. What should I do?

Comment: You know that DirectPlay has been deprecated? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I know, but I want to follow along with this book because it is one of the few I have found for DirectX that goes through making an entire game. I learn best by doing that.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?

Well, a **strong advice** is to forget about it. 
Don't spent your time to learn deprecated things. If your book using DirectPlay, probably it is better to put it out. Okay, maybe you will want look at game *design* features it recommends and nothing more. Anyway, you cannot learn gamedev when only reading *one* book.

***But...***
If you reaaly maniac... =) [Wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectPlay) that first version of SDK that doesn't have DirectPlay is Aug2007. Then, lastest DirectPlay version that you can find on Microsoft web-site is [DirectX SDK - (April 2006)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24982). You probably could find another version between April 2006 and August 2007.

*Offtopic (sorry for that):*
Best book I've ever seen about writing whole game from scratch is [Mr. Mike's Game Coding Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1133776574). In the end they implement a FPS-like game about teapot wars =) Modern DirectX, network, scripting, and many more.

Happy coding!